# Recording Audio Output from a Specific Program on Windows

Tags: windows, audio

Is there any way to record the sound output of a specific program on Windows? I already have a solution that uses WASAPI's loopback device to record all audio output to the speakers, but I would prefer to be able to record only the audio output of a specific program and ignore everything else. I assume this is possible using a virtual audio device, but I would like to avoid something so complicated if possible.

Comment: Indeed, in Win7 each app has its own channel in the windows audio mixer. I wonder if they're accessible... +1

Comment: hi, I'd like to know how you solve your problem. I just come across the same one. thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this post (which is very interesting in itself), there's a program called

[Virtual Audio Cable](http://badros.blogspot.com/2010/05/skype-as-whole-house-wireless.html)  which might do the trick for you....

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Audio Cable will do what you already mentioned when you said it captures all audio sent to it. 
You can a Virtual Line to be the default and then record that Virtual Line. You can Not select a specific program to do such a thing.
I have made a tutorial for using it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUQmkgw8Pjg
I use it to play music from youtube through my "mic" while playing games.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, You may check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-classic-samples/applicationloopbackaudio-sample/), which use ActivateAudioInterfaceAsync Win32 API ; "Note that this sample requires Windows 10 build 20348 or later."